# Creating Unique Key in Entity Framework Model First approach

Tags: entity-framework, unique-key

is there anyway to create unique key in model first approach? I tried but does not found any property in property box.

Answer (score 0):

With data-annotations
`[Key]` attribute over the property.

With fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<yourModel>().HasKey(t => t.yourProp);
```